# A function in the method in Python Class

Tags: python-3.x, class

Now I use the following code

```
class SessionGen (Users):

    def _d_session_id_generator(self):
        d_session_id = 0

        def thing(self):
            nonlocal d_session_id
            d_session_id += 1
            return str(d_session_id)

        return thing
```

In my program I change a method

```
Users._generate_session_id = SessionGen()._d_session_id_generator()
```

and after that I call it. i think it is not correct pythonic style. Could you please correct me.

Comment: Do you mean that you want bind the method `_d_session_id_generateor()` of class `SessionGen` to its superclass `Users` (meanwhile give it a new name)? Or you just want to call the method from subclass in a superclass?

Comment: I use it for my test purposes. I just need to redaclare a method in my superclass to get necessary d_session_id in my tests

Comment: just try `Users._generate_session_id = SessionGen()._d_session_id_generator`.

Comment: I mean definition of method in my class. Could you please review it?

Comment: Well, if you want dynamicly define a method in class `Users` in your program, the code indeed works, you just need to assign the existing method `_d_session_id_generator` to the method `Users._generate_session_id`, no matter that method exists or not. And I'm sorry if you don't mean that and could you please specify it.

Comment: Everything works but I suppose thst my class SessionGen that use method in method is not correct because of python style. I think it is not possible to write this way?